# Can someone explain about 온(溫)?

Tags: history-of-korean

I was reading a comic but then come this part about this region... i found it on korean dict but don't quite understand:
 우리나라 성(姓)의 하나. 본관은 경주(慶州), 금구(金溝), 청주(淸州) 등 10여 본이 현존한다.

Or you can give me some reference, where can i read about those. Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[온(溫)](https://ko.wikipedia.org/wiki/%EC%98%A8_(%EC%84%B1%EC%94%A8)) is a Korean family name (성姓).

In general, Korean family names are composed of one or more clans, or [본관(bongwan, 本貫)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bon-gwan). Quoting Wikipedia,

> A Korean clan is a group of people that share the same paternal ancestor and is indicated by the combination of a bon-gwan and a family name (clan name).
>
> Bon-gwan are used to distinguish different lineages that bear the same family name. For example, the Gyeongju Kim and the Gimhae Kim are considered different clans, even though they happen to share the same family name Kim. In this case, Gyeongju and Gimhae are the respective bon-gwan of these clans.

A clan is named after the origin of their ancestors or the clan founder. Sometimes, a clan branches out of another clan, sharing the family name but having a different clan name.

[경주](https://ko.wikipedia.org/wiki/%EA%B2%BD%EC%A3%BC%EC%8B%9C), [금구](https://ko.wikipedia.org/wiki/%EA%B8%88%EA%B5%AC%EB%A9%B4), and [청주](https://ko.wikipedia.org/wiki/%EC%B2%AD%EC%A3%BC%EC%8B%9C) are all place names, from which different clans of the family name On(온) come from.

So your sentence means:

> On(온) is a Korean family name. There are around ten clans, including Gyeongju(경주), Geumgu(금구), and 청주(Cheongju).

Answer (score 0):

In Indonesia 온 (溫) is a surname for Indonesians with Chinese ancestor.
In Indonesia, it is usually pronounced : Oen, Boen, Wen, Un